# Reference for the center of masses of some regular/symmetric bodies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

This [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) has been really helpful to me for quick reference of TeX commands.

I have been studying a chapter from my course book named **Center of mass, Linear momentum, and Collisions**. There are some derivations of the center of mass of some specific regular bodies but they are not satisfactory, i.e. C.O.M. of only 3-4 bodies are given in this textbook. For example, the center of mass of a solid hemisphere is given, but not the quarter sphere.

I wanted to find them and I also have found some. And for others, I searched on the internet but they are missing. So by reading this [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) an idea came to me: why not make a post where the derivations of C.O.M. of many of the regular bodies which are missing from the internet, are present?

So is this a good idea?

If yes, then I will edit this post, and furthermore, provide some derivations. Anyone can add their derivations of C.O.M of other bodies which are not present in the post already.

If not, then I will delete this post.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate volume integrals? it is what you need

Comment: See Wikipedia's [list of centroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centroids). You can edit the article if you think some centers of mass are missing, for example, the quarter ball or the hemispherical shell.

Comment: Hi Aditya. Questions like this, where the answer is a long list, are discouraged on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better yet is to derive the COM for whatever shape you want.

Here is how you do it. I am going to create an example of pizza pie, I mean a circular sector.

First derive an expression for all interior points to the solid, based on three parameters $(u,v,w)$ and some range

[image: fig1]

$$ \left.  \vec{\rm pos}(u,v,w)  = \pmatrix{ u  \sin \left(  v \right) \\  u  \cos \left( v \right) \\ w  } \right\} \begin{aligned} u &= 0 \ldots R  \\   v &= -\tfrac{1}{2}\psi \ldots \tfrac{1}{2}\psi \\ w &= -\tfrac{1}{2}b \ldots \tfrac{1}{2}b \end{aligned} $$

Then form the volume element based on the parameters

$$ {\rm d}V = \left|  \frac{ \partial \vec{\rm pos}}{\partial u} \cdot \left( \frac{ \partial \vec{\rm pos}}{\partial v}  \times \frac{ \partial \vec{\rm pos}}{\partial w} \right) \right|\;{\rm d}u \;{\rm d}v \; {\rm d}w = u  \;{\rm d}u \;{\rm d}v \; {\rm d}w$$

$$ V = \int_0^R \int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}b}^{\tfrac{1}{2}b} \int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}\psi}^{\tfrac{1}{2}\psi} u \;{\rm d}v \; {\rm d}w\;{\rm d}u = \frac{b \, \psi R^2}{2} $$

Now the center of mass is given by

$$ \vec{\rm cm} = \frac{1}{V} \int_0^R \int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}b}^{\tfrac{1}{2}b} \int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}\psi}^{\tfrac{1}{2}\psi} \vec{\rm pos} \,u \;{\rm d}v \; {\rm d}w\;{\rm d}u = 
\pmatrix{0 \\ \tfrac{4 R}{3 \psi} \sin \left( \frac{\psi}{2} \right) \\ 0 } $$

The above process works for *any* parametrization of a volume and once you have $V = \int_V {\rm d}V$ defined then

$$ m = \int_V \rho {\rm d}V $$

$$ \vec{cm} = \frac{1}{m} \int_V \vec{\rm pos}\, \rho {\rm d}V $$